# Environment variable `ENV` not set when running Flask app on OpenShift

Tags: python, flask, openshift, gunicorn, wsgi

I'm using the [s2i-python-container](https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container) to deploy my Flask 12.2 app on OpenShift 3 (so it is served by [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/)).

For some mysterious and frustrating reason, even though I have tried setting the environment variable `ENV` both in my `.s2i/environment` file and directly via OpenShift's environment configuration, in both cases the variable `ENV` is not set in my application pod.  It's just gone. My other environment variables are properly set.

What gives? Is there some other approach I should be taking to identify if I am in development or production to load the appropriate configuration?

Comment: Can you show code?

Comment: The ``ENV`` variable is special to shells and is used to dictate a script file that should be run when a new shell is started. Why do you want to override it? As is, the S2I image is using it for other purposes and unsets it in the script it runs using it. Overriding it will likely interfere with the image.

Comment: If you want to run your own additional steps when a new shell is started, you should append it to the end of ``/opt/app-root/etc/scl_enable`` script. You would have to add it there via a custom ``assemble`` script which adds it and then executes the original ``assemble`` script.

Comment: If this is just some flag for your code, using a different name for the environment variable.

Comment: Why the down vote?  @cwallenpoole: There is no code to show.  As the question specifies, the environment variable `ENV` which is set via the methods described is not present when the app is executed in the described environment.

Comment: @HolySamosa I didn't downvote you. But you are setting that *somewhere* and trying to read it *somewhere else*. Both of these are code.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks for the insight. I was using `ENV` to determine if the app is in `development` or `production` mode to load the appropriate configuration.  It's referenced in the Flask documentation (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/) and various examples online use it in such a manner.  Perhaps I should file an issue with `s2i-python-container` to suggest not unsetting `ENV`.  If you would like to provide your response as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Sorry, I didn't intend to imply that you down voted. It would have been more clear if there had been a newline separating my question about the down vote and my response to you.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Not sure you are understanding importance of what I am saying. The ``ENV`` environment variable is special for Bourne Shell and Bash. See discussion about ``ENV`` in https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh. If you use that environment variable and a sub shell gets created, the shell process will try and interpret it as a script file it should run. So is actually a really bad environment variable name to use because of its special meaning. The S2I image can't use a different name, as it is trying to use that feature of a shell. It can't not unset it as it only wants to do it once and not for sub shells.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks for the additional explanation, I now understand what you were saying.